# struts property tag inside struts if tag

Tags: struts2, ognl

How can I implement this without illegally nesting JSP tags?

```
<s:if test="<s:property value="#count" /> == <s:property value="%{arrayCount}" "/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't randomly nest tags like that, the same as with XML and HTML.

Use OGNL:

```
<s:if test="#count == arrayCount">
```

See [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl.html) and [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html) for some really basic OGNL info, and the [OGNL site](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/) for specifics.

Answer (score 4):

The Struts 2 `<s:if>` tag is capable enough to fetch values from the value stack or any other context so there is no need to use the property tag inside the if tag.

I assume that both `count` and `arrayCount` are available in your value stack, or you have set those in your action class/jsp page. All you need to do is:

```xml
<s:if test="#count == arrayCount">
  // do what ever you want 
</s:if>
```

Itss best to go through some basic OGNL syntax:

1. [OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl.html)
2. [OGNL Basics](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html)